# Google AutoComplete API getting "INVALID REQUEST"

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-api

I've to add google autocomplete api in my app but I don't know. I also getting "INVALID REQUEST". I also check [developer.google.com](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_types) but I can't find any solution. I am using AFNetwrok.

**Here is my code**

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@key=%@",AutoComplete_URL,GOOGLE_KEY];
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"input" : [@"Paris" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"],@"sensor":@"true"};
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager POST:strURL parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        if (responseObject) {
            [APPDELEGATE hideLoadingView];
            if ([[responseObject valueForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"OK"]) {
                arrAutocomplete = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"predictions"] valueForKey:@"description"];
                NSLog(@"AUTO: %@", arrAutocomplete);
            }
            else{
                // [APPDELEGATE showpToastWithTitle:[response valueForKey:@"msg"]];
                //[self.tableView setHidden:YES];
            }
        }
        else{
            [APPDELEGATE hideLoadingView];
            [APPDELEGATE showToastWithTitle:@"Please check your internet connection"];
        }
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        [APPDELEGATE hideLoadingView];
        [APPDELEGATE showToastWithTitle:@"Something going wrong"];
    }];
```

**OUTPUT :-**

JSON:

```
{
    predictions =     (
    );
    status = "INVALID_REQUEST";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it.

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=%@&types=geocode&input=%@",GOOGLE_KEY,address];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // 2
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        if (responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        // 4
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Weather"
                                                            message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }];

    // 5
    [operation start];
```